# How to run vmware .vmx on Mac?

Tags: ios, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a .vmx virtual machine created with VMware Workstation 10 on PC, and I need to run it on iOS 10.7.5. I installed VMware Fusion 6 ('cause you need 10.8 for Fusion 7), but when I try to use it, my .vmx files are all grey and unselectable to open. I feel really stupid about it, but I am really unfamiliar with iOS and hope someone can point me to right direction.

Upgrading iOS is not an option for me, and I'm not even sure if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open an existing virtual machine from the Virtual Machine Library window or from the applications menu.

Procedure

■ Open a virtual machine from the Virtual Machine Library.
a
From the VMware Fusion menu bar, select Window > Virtual Machine Library.
b
In the Virtual Machine Library window, select a virtual machine from the list of recognized virtual machines.
c
Click the run button.

■Open a virtual machine from the applications menu
a
Click the applications menu status item (The applications menu icon is a small monochromatic version of the VMware Fusion logo.) in the menu bar.
The applications menu appears, displaying the most recently accessed virtual machine in the blue title bar.
b
Click the pop-up menu in the title bar and select the virtual machine.
c
Click Resume or Start Up.